# how to write accessible html table?

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility

A table on my site has been flagged by an accessibility plugin (aXe). After some tinkering, it ended up saying that I had to fix the following two things:

1. `<th>` elements should only be used when there is a single row and
   single column of headers
2. Table has cells whose rowspan attribute is not equal to 1

How can I reasonably build a table with nested levels of information without violating at least one of those?

My table code is:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Type Of</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2">Blue</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2">Green</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td scope="col" class="centered">Light Blue</td>
            <td scope="col" class="centered">Dark Blue</td>
            <td scope="col" class="centered">Light Green</td>
            <td scope="col" class="centered">Dark Green</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Type 1</th>
            <td class="centered">Y</td>
            <td class="centered">Y</td>
            <td class="centered">Y</td>
            <td class="centered">N</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Type 2</th>
            <td class="centered">Y</td>
            <td class="centered">Y</td>
            <td class="centered">Y</td>
            <td class="centered">N</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Type 3</th>
            <td class="centered">Y</td>
            <td class="centered">Y</td>
            <td class="centered">Y</td>
            <td class="centered">N</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessibility tools are free to invent their own rules, but this tool is wrong saying you should remove table headers `th` when you use `rowspan` or `colspan`. It's totally wrong. Check that you have the last version of this tool : this is an awful advice.

In your case, you can use the following technique to mark column headers:
[H43: Using id and headers attributes to associate data cells with header cells in data tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H43.html)

Your have one problem in your example:
Your headers in your second line are not marked as column headers (`th`) (and `headers` attribute should only reference `th` with `id`).

You markup should be something like:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" id="typeof">Type Of</th>
        <th colspan="2" id="blue">Blue</th>
        <th colspan="2" id="green">Green</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th id="lightblue">Light</th>
        <th id="darkblue">Dark</th>
        <th id="lightgreen">Light</th>
        <th id="darkgreen">Dark</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th id="type1" headers="typeof">Type 1</th>
        <td headers="type1 lightblue" title="Yes">Y</td>
        <td headers="type1 darkblue" title="Yes">Y</td>
        <td headers="type1 lightgreen" title="Yes">Y</td>
        <td headers="type1 darkgreen" title="No">N</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th id="type2" headers="typeof">Type 2</th>
        <td headers="type2 lightblue" title="Yes">Y</td>
        <td headers="type2 darkblue" title="Yes">Y</td>
        <td headers="type2 lightgreen" title="Yes">Y</td>
        <td headers="type2 darkgreen" title="No">N</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th id="type3" headers="typeof">Type 3</th>
        <td headers="type3 lightblue" title="Yes">Y</td>
        <td headers="type3 darkblue" title="Yes">Y</td>
        <td headers="type3 lightgreen" title="Yes">Y</td>
        <td headers="type3 darkgreen" title="No">N</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Also, I added a `title` attribute in order to add a speakable alternative for screen readers (you could have used `aria-label` but `title` adds a tooltip for other people, except it is not keyboard friendly). Better choice would be to have here a full word.

Comment: I began to assume that something was wrong with the tool after getting the same errors from testing it on a table-filled page at webaim.org.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what tool you are using, but have you tried using `col` and `colgroup` elements?  There is some basic information [here](http://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/) from W3C about irregular headers in data tables.

Also, I put together a quick JSFiddle based on your table if you want to look at that: https://jsfiddle.net/dngvc84o/

Comment: Make sure your use <thead> and <tbody> to identify which parts of the table contain header information and which contain data.

Comment: I'm using the aXe plugin. It looks like nothing with a rowspan above 1 will pass, because not all screenreaders provide the same level of support for it.

Comment: Also @DarrenS using <thead> and <tbody> has no effect on the violations listed by aXe.